# IPTV UDP Proxy на роутере

Tags: роутер, proxy

Есть роутер: tp-link TL-1043ND. Имеется провайдер с IPTV. И имеется устройство на андроиде (имеется соответствующее ПО). Плейлист добавил, список каналов выводится. Но пишется, что надо настроить UDP прокси. Можно ли это сделать без каких - либо сторонних прошивок на роутере, что указан выше?

Comment: мде, не густо тут у вас. )

Answer (score 1):

в стандарте роутера таких настроек нет

Comment: в какой из сторонних прошивок, которые есть под этот роутер, есть поддержка PPPoE Russia?  DD-WRT, во всяком случае на LinkSys WRT-54GL подтормаживала, особенно при загрузке торрентов.